# Create JDBC Connection pool only accepts one operand for Oracle on GlassFish

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, glassfish, server

[after to fail to create a jdbc connection pool through glassfish admin console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277841/glassfish-console-http-status-500-internal-server-error-by-adding-jdbc-connect)
i tried to create a JDBC Connection Pool for Oracle on GlassFish through the Windows command line by typing in this command

```
 create-jdbc-connection-pool 
 –datasourceclassname oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource 
 –restype javax.sql.DataSource 
 –property user=user1:password=topSecret:URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" MyExampleDB
```

I get the following error message:

[image: Watch this picture]

Please help?
Is it even possible to create a JDBC Connection Pool with GlassFish?
Or better to migrate to WildFly?

Comment: Please don't provide information that can be text as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it's possible to create JDBC Pool in glassfish

I'm not sure about command line syntax, but via admin console it pretty easy

see admin console: http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf
Resources -> JDBC - > JDBC Connection Pools

upd:

command line example

```
asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool 
--restype=java.sql.Driver
--driverclassname=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
--property user=myuser:password=mypassword:url='jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe'
test_ora_pool
```